# Inserting iframe via Angular ng-repeat on view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have an array of objects, that I am iterating through on my view. One of the fields in my object is an iframe string.

Here is what my view code looks like...

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="x in data">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h3 class="pull-left counterSettings">#1   </h3>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          {{{x.embed}}}
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="row">
                feel: {{x.subreddit}} <br>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-lg arrowStyle">   {{x.score}} reddit votes</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The triple handle bars I am currently using do not work. Angular throws the following error.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{x.embed] starting at [.embed].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7Bx.embed&p4=.embed
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12)
    at Object.AST.throwError (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13010:11)
    at Object.AST.consume (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13022:12)
    at Object.AST.object (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12999:14)
    at Object.AST.primary (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12905:22)
    at Object.AST.unary (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12893:19)
    at Object.AST.multiplicative (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12880:21)
    at Object.AST.additive (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12871:21)
    at Object.AST.relational (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12862:21)
    at Object.AST.equality (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12853:21) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

The string in x.embed looks like the following.

```
<iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F4xOmwQD0Dm8%3Ffeature%3Doembed&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4xOmwQD0Dm8&image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F4xOmwQD0Dm8%2Fhqdefault.jpg&key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&type=text%2Fhtml&schema=youtube\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>
```

Comment: {{{x.embed}}}   change to {{x.embed}}

Comment: @jackk that just displays the text. I want it to actually embed the media player on the page